# adding and embedding a pdf-document to a github-page

Tags: html, github, jekyll, github-pages

can i add PDFs to a page - is this possible?

how to do this - how to place them on the page!?

i thougth that the solution is this one:

to embed the PDF in the web page.  we can upload the CV PDF file to the repository, then use some HTML to embed it.

```
`<object data="myfile.pdf" width="1000" height="1000" type='application/pdf'/>`
```

**but wait**: i am trying to test several modes of embedding: which one runs with some effect - which one does work. no one so far: What to do now!?

cf.: https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/issues/2361

which one runs with some effect - which one does work. no one so far: What to do now!?

**neither this one**

```
--- #
title: "Résumé"
permalink: /resume/
header:
---
[See it here :)](http://ToadHanks.github.io/images/mihir_resume_2019v5.pdf)
Then I get a link that opens to new tab instead of a pdf embedded page. However, I have saved to pdf to image, and was able to display that in the page.
```

**nor this one:**

```
#https://raw.githubusercontent.com/belovanna/belovanna.github.io/b64e6c285e0e057f9bc9a1723a4eb767446a1947/_pages/curriculum.md
Effect: https://belovanna.github.io/Curriculum/
```

see the poor results: https://fsj-digital.github.io/DigitalHub/

what can i do now!?

**update:**  well i think that i ll do it like so: like it is described here:

https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet

> Links There are two ways to create links.
>
> [I'm an inline-style link](https://www.google.com)
>
> [I'm an inline-style link with title](https://www.google.com)
>
> [I'm a reference-style link](https://www.mozilla.org)
>
> I'm a relative reference to a repository
> file
>
> [You can use numbers for reference-style link definitions][1]
>
> Or leave it empty and use the [link text itself].
>
> URLs and URLs in angle brackets will automatically get turned into
> links.  http://www.example.com or http://www.example.com and
> sometimes  example.com (but not on Github, for example).
>
> Some text to show that the reference links can follow later.
>
> [1]: http://slashdot.org [link text itself]: http://www.reddit.com

Comment: Well, what about saving a pdf file in the same repo of the site and use its path to retrieve it from embedded word.

https://[repo].github.io/assets/my_file.pdf

just my 2 cents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That comment was just linking to where their example is (albeit in an odd manner). This is [the code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/belovanna/belovanna.github.io/b64e6c285e0e057f9bc9a1723a4eb767446a1947/_pages/curriculum.md), which when rendered appears [like this](https://belovanna.github.io/Curriculum/). It looks like they also made [a blog post describing it](https://belovanna.github.io/website/update/linking-to-pdf-in-jekyll/).

You might need to resize the embed, in which case [this MDN entry should be helpful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed).

Comment: hello dear Cameron - many thanks for the answer - so if i got you right then i am able to link to a pdf document - no matter where it is located!? Is this true!?

Comment: Yes, as long as you have a direct link to the PDF you should be able to embed it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you resolved this one or not. But for adding embedding a PDF file to GitHub Pages, in my case, I just need to add the PDF file to the `assets` folder, and then I can access the file through its link. For example:

`../assets/your-resume.pdf`

```
assets
|___files
|  |___your-resume.pdf
|__...
```

And your GitHub Pages URL: `you.github.io`

Then here is your embedding PDF resume URL: `you.github.io/assets/files/your-resume.pdf`